# Ramer Douglas Peucker Algorithmn (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, line-segment

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to understand what's happening here in these lines of code. I understand the algorithm and how it works but I am struggling to decode what is happening here in the code and how it is working to simplify the line segment.

This might sound a bit silly but if anyone could break this down for me it would be a great help! Cheers

Here is the Code:

```
def douglas_peuker_recursive(point_list, e):
    dmax = 0
    index = -1
  
    for i in range(1, len(point_list)):
        point = Point(point_list[i])
        line = LineString([point_list[0], point_list[-1]])
        d = point.distance(line)
        if d > dmax:
            index = i
            dmax = d
    if dmax > e:
        r1 = douglas_peuker_recursive(point_list[:index+1], e)
        r2 = douglas_peuker_recursive(point_list[index:], e)
        return r1[:-1] + r2
    else:
        return [point_list[0], point_list[-1]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried asking the person who wrote this code? We also have no idea what Point and LineString are

Comment: @Codist thanks for the response. My apologies for the poor post, I am new to this. The Point and Linestring are geometry that is imported from shapely using "from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString". Sorry again for not providing the necessary info. I'm doing my best here! Let me know if you would like to see anything else.